# Hiding div until jquery datepicker shows

Tags: jquery, datepicker, show-hide

Is it possible with jquery to hide a div until the jquery ui datepicker loads? I have a section on the site that shows the calendar inline using the jquery ui datepicker. Sometimes the datepicker doesnt load right away so the content below it shows at the top, then gets pushed down once the datepicker loads. I rather the div below the datepicker not show until the datepicker has loaded and is displayed. Is this possible? If so, how would I tell the datepicker loaded and be able to display the div after that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the div in css (`display:none`) and then using jQuery, run a function when the div is finished loading.

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/UudrH/2/

Your code would look something like this:

```
$("#wait").ready(function(){
    $("#hidden").show();   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the height of the datepicker you can preset the containing div to that height. That way there will be no movement and it will just fill the space already allotted for it.